# Convergence and limit of Muller sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, recursion, floating-point

The Muller sequence is given by the recursive definition:

$U(n+1)=111-\frac{1130}{U(n)}+\frac{3000}{U(n)U(n-1)}$ with $U(0)=5.5$ and $U(1)=\frac{61}{11}$.

This sequence is interesting in floating-point arithmetic because it fails to converge numerically while it converges theoretically and has the limit 6 [(more info)](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/cadna/Examples_Dir/ex4.php).

But, how to prove theoretically that this sequence converges to its limit?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to read the paper claiming this, I couldn't find a source other than your link. I haven't dealt with such sequences before, but it does sound strange that there exists a limit. Namely, if a limit $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} U(n)$ exists, it is the same as $\lim_{n\to \infty} U(n+1)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} U(n-1)$. So the recursive definition gives a cubic equation in $L$ whose solutions are $5,6,100$, making me think there's no limit at all.

Comment: $(x-5)(x-6)(x-100)=0$ has those solutions.

Comment: @MattSamuel And indeed that is equivalent to $$x^3-111x^2+1130x-3000=0$$.